# Using Liferay Auto Field in my custom portlet?

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-aui

In my custom portlet this is my `view.jsp` :

```
    <h1>Liferay auto fields example</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="LiferayAautoFieldForm">
<fieldset><legend>Phone Numbers</legend>
<div id="phone-fields">
<div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">
<div class="row-fields">
<input id='phoneNumber0' name="phoneNumber0" label="Phone Number" />
<select id="phoneTypeId0" name="phoneTypeId0" label="Type">
<option value="11006" label="Business">Business</option>
<option value="11007" label="Business Fax">Business Fax</option>
<option value="11008" label="Mobile Phone">Mobile Phone</option>
<option value="11009" label="Other">Other</option>
<option value="11011" label="Personal">Personal</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<layout>
<column>
<button type="submit" value="Save Phone Numbers" name="SavePhoneNumbers">Save Phone Numbers</button>
</column>
</layout>
</form>
```

I want to use new `Liferay.AutoFields` among  tag for increasing these two fields. For this aim I use this code in `view.jsp` :

```
<aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
new Liferay.AutoFields(
{
contentBox: '#phone-fields',
fieldIndexes: 'phonesIndexes'
}
).render();
</aui:script>
```

But It has problem, after add this code and deploy my portlet I can add/delete row but after adding some rows and delete them the id of **phoneNumber0** becomes wrong. Actually the sequence of phoneNumber0 doesn't regular!

How can I solve this issue?
Please guide me?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing??

Comment: @PankajKathiriya, after add some new rows the id of the input regularly increase phoneNumber0,1,2,... but after delete some rows this sequence mixed
and for the next time that I want to add row
I have not a reqular sequence

Comment: Hi my auto field is working perfectly if I add only input type text and select list, but when I am adding a button then after addition newly created button id is same as previous one, other field id is incrementing by one as usual. please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the Liferay source to use "liferay-auto-fields".

> ROOT\html\portlet\users_admin\common\phone_numbers.jsp.

They have used auto fields for similar requirement as yours.